# How do I copy, but not deepcopy, a networkx Graph?

Tags: networkx, deep-copy

I want to compare the state of a `networkx.Graph` object `n` before a function call `d(n)` (with side effects) with the state afterwards.

There are mutable object node attributes such as `n.node[0]['attribute']`, which I want to compare.

Obviously,

```
before = n
d()
after = n
assert id(before.node[0]['attribute']) == id(after.node[0]['attribute'])
```

succeeds trivially, because

```
before == after
```

but if I set `before=n.copy()`, a deep copy is made, and therefore `id(before.node[0]['attribute']) != id(after.node[0]['attribute'])`. How do I get a copy of a Graph object without copying all node attribute objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Networkx copy clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29854387/networkx-copy-clarification)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Calling the `copy` method gives a deep copy.  All attributes of the new graph are copies of the original graph.   Calling the constructor (e.g. `Graph(G)`) gives a shallow copy where the graph structure is copied but the data attributes are references those in the original graph.

From the `copy` method docs

> All copies reproduce the graph structure, but data attributes may be
>   handled in different ways. There are four types of copies of a graph
>   that people might want.
>
> Deepcopy -- The default behavior is a "deepcopy" where the graph
>   structure as well as all data attributes and any objects they might
>   contain are copied. The entire graph object is new so that changes in
>   the copy do not affect the original object.
>
> Data Reference (Shallow) -- For a shallow copy (with_data=False) the
>   graph structure is copied but the edge, node and graph attribute dicts
>   are references to those in the original graph. This saves time and
>   memory but could cause confusion if you change an attribute in one
>   graph and it changes the attribute in the other.

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx

In [2]: G = nx.Graph()

In [3]: G.add_node(1, color=['red'])

In [4]: G_deep = G.copy()

In [5]: G_deep.node[1]['color'].append('blue')

In [6]: list(G.nodes(data=True))
Out[6]: [(1, {'color': ['red']})]

In [7]: list(G_deep.nodes(data=True))
Out[7]: [(1, {'color': ['red', 'blue']})]

In [8]: G_shallow = nx.Graph(G)

In [9]: G_shallow.node[1]['color'].append('blue')

In [10]: list(G.nodes(data=True))
Out[10]: [(1, {'color': ['red', 'blue']})]

In [11]: list(G_shallow.nodes(data=True))
Out[11]: [(1, {'color': ['red', 'blue']})]
```

Comment: This seems no longer true since version 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
G = # your graph
G2 = nx.Graph() # or whatever type of graph `G` is
G2.add_edges_from(G.edges())
```

Answer (score -1):

Please also note that if your networkx graph contains objects of objects..., even a deepcopy would not work. It would return an error that there are too many levels.

Normally, I would think what exactly is of interest in the graph and just create a new one with that.